# Creating a lengthy box shadow (bottom) in css

Tags: html, css

How do I add a lengthy box shadow for a button using css as shown in the image of the link shown below?

[image]

I have tried using the 
box-shadow: -1px 11px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.71); But this does not produce a lengthy shadow. Really appreciate if someone could help me out.

Comment: There are two images, which one do you want?

Comment: Is this close to what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/fdoptx4h/ It is a little hard to see in the image, all black and gray...

Comment: @apaul34208 - Here is your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/fdoptx4h/1/) with some tweeks

Comment: @chipChocolate.py thanks much nicer, I'm still not sure if that is what sweety is really after though...

Comment: Thanks @chipChocolate.py and apaul34208. That helped alot! Appreciate it much :)